# Sqlite display table with informations about the databas

Tags: database, sqlite, create-table

They are asking me to write a query that display the following table:
[image]

- Select each table as a string
- Select the number of attributes as an integer (count the number of attributes per table).
- Select the number of rows using the COUNT(*) function
- Use the compound-operator UNION ALL to bind these rows together.

How do I do that?

I knew that for getting the name of each table I have to use

```
SELECT name AS table_name
  FROM sqlite_schema
 WHERE type = 'table'
```

but the rest is a mistery to me.
Would you help me?

Thank you!!!

[Here you can find the database](https://dq-content.s3.amazonaws.com/600/stores.db)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just had the same question, and the answer boiled down to 'manually' (looking at the schema visualisation or the aforementioned query for inputs). >_<

```
SELECT 'Customers' AS table_name, 
       13 AS number_of_attribute,
       COUNT(*) AS number_of_row
  FROM Customers
  
UNION ALL

SELECT 'Products' AS table_name, 
       9 AS number_of_attribute,
       COUNT(*) AS number_of_row
  FROM Products

UNION ALL

SELECT 'ProductLines' AS table_name, 
       4 AS number_of_attribute,
       COUNT(*) AS number_of_row
  FROM ProductLines

UNION ALL

SELECT 'Orders' AS table_name, 
       7 AS number_of_attribute,
       COUNT(*) AS number_of_row
  FROM Orders

UNION ALL

SELECT 'OrderDetails' AS table_name, 
       5 AS number_of_attribute,
       COUNT(*) AS number_of_row
  FROM OrderDetails

UNION ALL

SELECT 'Payments' AS table_name, 
       4 AS number_of_attribute,
       COUNT(*) AS number_of_row
  FROM Payments

UNION ALL

SELECT 'Employees' AS table_name, 
       8 AS number_of_attribute,
       COUNT(*) AS number_of_row
  FROM Employees

UNION ALL

SELECT 'Offices' AS table_name, 
       9 AS number_of_attribute,
       COUNT(*) AS number_of_row
  FROM Offices;
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of defining fixed values, what may lead to wrong answers once we add or remove columns from a given table, uses the following:

```sql
SELECT "Customer" AS table_name,
       (SELECT count(*) 
          FROM pragma_table_info('customers')) AS number_of_attributes, 
       count(*) AS number_of_rows
  FROM customers;
```